# How to prevent re-rendering with callbacks as props in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, usecallback

I'm practicing with the new hooks functionnality in ReactJS by refactoring the code from this [tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) with TypeScript.

I am passing a callback from a parent component to a child component threw props that has to be executed on a click button event.

My problem is this: I have an **alert** dialog that appears **twice** instead of once when the game has been won.
I assumed this was caused by a component re-rendering so I used the `useCallback` hook to memoize the `handleClickOnSquare` callback. The thing is, the alert dialog still appears twice.

I guess I'm missing something that has a relation with re-rendering, does someone have an idea what might cause this behavior ?

Here is my code:

**Game.tsx**

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import './Game.css';

interface SquareProps {
    onClickOnSquare: HandleClickOnSquare
    value: string;
    index: number;
}

const Square: React.FC<SquareProps> = (props) => {
    return (
        <button
            className="square"
            onClick={() => props.onClickOnSquare(props.index)}
        >
            {props.value}
        </button>
    );
};

interface BoardProps {
    squares: Array<string>;
    onClickOnSquare: HandleClickOnSquare
}

const Board: React.FC<BoardProps> = (props) => {

    function renderSquare(i: number) {
        return (
            <Square
                value={props.squares[i]}
                onClickOnSquare={props.onClickOnSquare}
                index={i}
            />);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="board-row">
                {renderSquare(0)}
                {renderSquare(1)}
                {renderSquare(2)}
            </div>
            <div className="board-row">
                {renderSquare(3)}
                {renderSquare(4)}
                {renderSquare(5)}
            </div>
            <div className="board-row">
                {renderSquare(6)}
                {renderSquare(7)}
                {renderSquare(8)}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export const Game: React.FC = () => {

    const [history, setHistory] = useState<GameHistory>(
        [
            {
                squares: Array(9).fill(null),
            }
        ]
    );
    const [stepNumber, setStepNumber] = useState(0);
    const [xIsNext, setXIsNext] = useState(true);

    const handleClickOnSquare = useCallback((index: number) => {
        const tmpHistory = history.slice(0, stepNumber + 1);
        const current = tmpHistory[tmpHistory.length - 1];
        const squares = current.squares.slice();

        // Ignore click if has won or square is already filled
        if (calculateWinner(squares) || squares[index]) return;

        squares[index] = xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
        setHistory(tmpHistory.concat(
            [{
                squares: squares,
            }]
        ));
        setStepNumber(tmpHistory.length);
        setXIsNext(!xIsNext);
    }, [history, stepNumber, xIsNext]);

    const jumpTo = useCallback((step: number) => {
        setHistory(
            history.slice(0, step + 1)
        );
        setStepNumber(step);
        setXIsNext((step % 2) === 0);
    }, [history]);

    const current = history[stepNumber];
    const winner = calculateWinner(current.squares);

    const moves = history.map((step, move) => {
        const desc = move ?
            'Go back to move n°' + move :
            'Go back to the start of the party';

        return (
            <li key={move}>
                <button onClick={() => jumpTo(move)}>{desc}</button>
            </li>
        );
    });

    let status: string;
    if (winner) {
        status = winner + ' won !';
        alert(status);
    } else {
        status = 'Next player: ' + (xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O');
    }

    return (
        <div className="game">
            <div className="game-board">
                <Board
                    squares={current.squares}
                    onClickOnSquare={handleClickOnSquare}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="game-info">
                <div>{status}</div>
                <ol>{moves}</ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

function calculateWinner(squares: Array<string>): string | null {
    const lines = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6],
    ];
    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
        if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
            return squares[a];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**types.d.ts**

```
type GameHistory = Array<{
    squares: Array<string>
}>;

type HandleClickOnSquare = (index: number) => void;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is too long to find the cause of extra rerender. Note that React might need an [extra render](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update).

To avoid an extra `alert` use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect):

```
let status: string;
if (winner) {
    status = winner + ' won !';
} else {
    status = 'Next player: ' + (xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O');
}
useEffect(() => {
    if (winner) alert(status)
}, [winner]);
```